# Verb form after "but"

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if infinitive form is used after "but" in these three sentences

> He was made not to do anything but **go** to bed right then.
>
> He didn't do anything but **play** computer games all day.
>
> He did nothing but **play** computer games all day.

Is there any situation where infinitive form is not used after "but"?

Comment: Usually it's infinitive, to+infinitive or gerund, but in past tense you use past forms... although I can't think of a practical example in any past tense right now. Are you interested in every possibility with verbs and auxiliary verbs? There may be a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding these sentences is the word **do** in the first part of each sentence. If we shorten **do nothing but** and **not do anything but** to **do**, we get

> He did go to bed right then
>   he did play computer games all day

In these sentences, **do** is functioning as an auxiliary verb: when used like this, it is followed by a bare infinitive - one without a **to**.

Comment: I've just seen this sentence: He had no choice but to obey. Could you tell me why to+V form is used in this sentence?

Comment: If you take 'no choice but' out, the sentence becomes 'He had to obey'. You can only have one true verb in a sentence and thus 'to' is necessary. To make obey an infinitive, to was added. Of course, you can say 'He had obeyed', but that gives the sentence a different meaning.

Comment: While the sentences you have constructed are correct, 'but' cannot be taken out the way you have suggested. 'But' is similar to 'and', and would split a sentence especially when there are two distinct meanings in the first and the second sentence. Notice that "He did nothing" and "He did not do anything" are actual sentences that can stand on their own. The 'did' in that case will not carry across the 'but' as suggested. See the edits below on my original answer, and sorry for the error in the original post.~

Comment: But having said that, this still doesn't give a proper answer for the last question: 'Is there any situation where infinitive form is not used after "but"?'

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences are correct -

> ***1.*** He was made not to do anything but ***(to)*** *go* to bed right then.
>
> ***2.*** He didn't do anything but *play* computer games all day.
>
> ***3.*** He did nothing but *play* computer games all day.

The preposition *but* here license *Matrix-licensed Complement*. And so what will follow after *but* will completely depend on the Matrix Clause.

In sentence #1, the use of *to* after *but* is optional. The Matrix clause is *The only thing he was made to do was* (to) *go to bed right then*. Most common practice is to remove *to* after *but* in this case.

In sentence #2, the matrix clause is *He only played computer games all day*. So before *play* we don't need any *to*, hence in your second sentence it's actually incorrect to add *to* after *but*. It's fine without *to*.

Similar thing happens for sentence #3. In that sentence the matrix clause is *He only played computer games all day*. So before *play* we don't need any *to*, hence in your third sentence it's actually incorrect to add *to* after *but*. It's fine without *to*.

But there are situations where both adding *to* and omitting *to* after *but* in similar sentences are permitted. For example -

> **4.** There is nothing else to do but wait and see.
>
> **5.** There is nothing else to do but to wait and see.

Both are perfectly valid and grammatically correct sentence. Both of them mean the same thing - *the only thing to do is (to) wait and see*.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, all three should have 'to' added.

---

Edited x3:
After doing some really serious thinking, this is what I have…

Only the first required 'to' (not optional). The other two are optional.

1) Corrected:
He was made not to do anything, but to go to bed right then.

Explanation:
You cannot have two verbs in a sentence. While it is ok to say 'he went to bed right then', your meaning is 'he was made to go to bed right then'. 'To' is needed to create an infinitive. But is a conjunction joining the sentences. 'was not made to do anything' is not a rhetorical addition and has actual meaning. They have to be considered as separate sentences.

2) Corrected:
He didn't do anything, but played computer games all day.

Explanation:
Notice that 'He played computer games all day.' is a valid sentence and is the actual meaning of the sentence.

3) Corrected:
He did nothing, but played computer games all day.

Explanation:
Same as 2).

My opinion:
Do auxiliary and bare infinitives as an explanation cannot be considered correct in this case. The 'real ' sentence here is 'he played computer games all day', and not 'he did play computer games all day'. Both of the sentences are correct, but there is a subtle difference - we are not trying to emphasize he DID play computer games all day; we are just stating the fact he played. 'Doing nothing' is simply a rhetorical addition. Thus, I consider it more appropriate to consider 'do' as a principle verb of the do nothing sentence, and splitting the sentence into two. (He didn't do anything. He played games the whole day.)

So why are some other folks saying that this is ok? One other way to understand this is to break the sentence up by itself. Take #3 as an example... The structure of the sentence is essentially "He did nothing but (this) all day." The 'this' chunk in here can be 'play computer games' / 'playing computer games' / 'to play computer games'. Since people sometimes drop the 'to' with infinitives, it is technically correct. But that this breakdown does not give the sentence its intended meaning by adding the auxiliary verb 'do', and 'did nothing' added a different meaning than 'did play', the more appropriate way to say this would be to view the sentences as two separate parts.

'But' has a special place in this conversation and people do use bare infinitives with it. Consider this - if you replace the 'but's with 'other than' / 'except', would a gerund or a 'to' be more appropriate? I think most will agree with having a gerund / 'to' in that situation. Thus, 'but' is the reason why some may consider it correct to go with bare infinitives vs full infinitives. The use of nothing but in this case is a rather informal way of saying the same thing as using other than / except. You will not likely see this a lot in formal writing.

---

Edited: Adding last question's answer~

You can use something other than an infinitive after 'but'. But I don't believe there is a hard and fast rule for it as Korvin said. Generally, if you take the rhetorical part out, it will make things clearer for you on whether to is needed or not.

Comment: Incorrect.  None of those examples require 'to' as written and would not normally be seen with a 'to' inserted.